# Oracle Report6i - Export to Excel Option/Button

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Please guide me that how to enable option/button on oracle report 6i to export it into excel format

Waiting for your response

BR

Javed Akram

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as far as I can tell. Reports 6i don't have option of saving result into native MS Excel format.

The closest thing you could do is to set `desformat` to `delimited`:

> Means that the report output is sent to a file that can be read by standard spreadsheet utilities, such as Microsoft Excel. If you do not choose a delimiter, then the default delimiter is a TAB.

(see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/forms.6i/a83592/pbr_clia.htm))